# Global variables in C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, global-variables

How can i write all these global variables of C++ in Java?

```
  //Global variables
  int charClass;
  char lexeme [100];
  char nextChar;
  int lexLen;
  int token;
  int nextToken;
  extern string word("Apple");
```

Comment: Is this homework? And what have you tried?

Comment: all lines are valid Java, except for the last, he that is what you mean.

Comment: and the char array isn't valid Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about public static variables in a class?

```
public class Globals {
    public static int charClass;
    public static char[] lexeme = new char[100];
    public static char nextChar;
    public static int lexLen;
    public static int token;
    public static int nextToken;
    public static String word = "Apple";
}
```

There are several differences but the main idea is similar (as least for the primitives).